# How to create Frames in ASP.NET (to show other URLs within ASP.NET site)

Tags: asp.net, frame, target, master-pages

Scenario : ASP.NET site with masterpage that has top, left and side bars. The body of the page sometimes needs to be shown the data from other urls. For example there will be a hyperlink on the masterpage called "Show Cities". Clicking on this link will open a new window with url "https://yourcompany/cities.aspx". This ASPX is not linked to the ASP.NET site.

I would like to change this to show "https://yourcompany/cities.aspx" within ASP.NET site itself. So when users click on "Show cities", the site will show header, top, left and the body will show whatever results cities.aspx shows.

What is the best approach and suggestions? Is it like I need to create frames? Need some assistance in this regard.

More information on this:
MasterPage has few hyperlinks or buttons such as Show Cities, Show Dealers etc. Clicking on ShowCities should show yourcompany/cities.aspx (external site) and similarly "ShowDealers" click should show "mycompany.com/ShowDealers.aspx";. So each link has it's own unique click and results but results should be shown within our site such that user should not feel he is being redirected somewhere. Also the area/boundary where it shows the result should not show the URL of that external site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markup:

```
<iframe id="yourid" runat="server" src="http://initialsource.aspx"> </iframe>
```

And on code behind...

```
  yourid.src="http://to-the-new-site.aspx";
```

I think it should work.

**UPDATE** - providing js version:

If you define a javascript function like this:

```
function setFrameSrc(newSrc)
{
    document.getElementyById('yourid').src=newSrc;
    //note: 'yourid' is the iframe id from my initial example.
}
```

And you have your link like this:

```
function setFrameSrc(newSrc)
{
    document.getElementById('yourid').src=newSrc;
    //note: 'yourid' is the iframe id from my initial example.
}
```

Will work. [Test here.](http://jsfiddle.net/KDCAc/)

Comment: I have few links on the master page that are all external pages. All of them should be shown within the frame. Considering the above, please tell me where to incorporate the above changes? thanks.

Comment: @Anirudh I thought the interaction was something like: user clicks on a link that says "Shows Sites" that displays a list of links to different sites (presumably populated in a repeater; for example). Then by clicking on the particular link inside the repeater, you display the content of that site inside the iframe. Confirm that's the case and I'll provide some guidance.

Comment: @Lcarus: It is like this. MasterPage has few hyperlinks or buttons such as Show Cities, Show Dealers etc. Clicking on ShowCities should show http://yourcompany/cities.aspx (external site) and similarly "ShowDealers" click should show "http://mycompany.com/ShowDealers.aspx". So each link has it's own unique click and results but results should be shown within our site such that user should not feel he is being redirected somewhere. Also the area/boundary where it shows the result should not show the URL of that external site.

Comment: @Anirudh you should be able to use pure javascript for that. Will provide a js example.

Comment: @Anirudh provided an example.

Comment: @Lcarus:thanks for the details. I am still not clear in understanding and it is my mistake. Currently I just have masterpage with those 2 hyperlinks on the top right in masterpage. Can you tell me what and tell I need to do in masterpage (and it's cs file)? Also how does the click event know which portion of the page should be filled with the external page? Please provide some steps in implementing...thanks

Comment: @anIrudh rather than me continuing guessing, why don't you post either markup or at least a picture. You can remove/hide anything confidential. Just leave the important pieces.

Comment: @Lcarus: I am working on the suggestions but have few issues / bottlenecks. I will get back within an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where the source is coming from and your target audience.  You could create the cities.aspx page within your master page and simply set the body of it to be an IFrame with the target page as the source.

Works pretty well, but some mobile devices do not support iFrames.

Comment: I have few links on the master page that are all external pages. All of them should be shown within the frame. Should I create one ASPX page called 'ShowContent.aspx'? Please give me some steps as to what needs to be modified in master-page and anywhere else.